# javascript alternating color rows of tables

Tags: javascript

I have a page with several tables on it with the same class name.  I want to alternate the colors of the rows of every table on this page.  I'm using the code below with .  This code isn't working correctly, because only 1 table is alternating colors at a time (the first table).  what am I doing wrong?  All the tables on my page has "mytable" class.

```
function altrows(classname,firstcolor,secondcolor)
{
    var tableElements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname) ;
    for(var j= 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
    {
        var table = tableElements[j] ;

        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i=i+2)
        {
            rows[i].bgColor = firstcolor ;
            rows[i+1].bgColor = secondcolor ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` will not work in all browsers, as not all browsers have support for it- see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of your tables has an odd number of rows, your function will break on the line

```
        rows[i+1].bgColor = secondcolor ;
```

and not process any of the following tables. You should either check whether there is a row before setting the secondcolor:

```
function altrows(classname,firstcolor,secondcolor)
{
   var tableElements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname) ;
   for(var j= 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
   {
      var table = tableElements[j] ;

      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i=i+2)
      {
        rows[i].bgColor = firstcolor ;
        if ( i+1 < rows.length ) {
            rows[i+1].bgColor = secondcolor ;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

or loop over every row rather than looping over sets of two rows:

```
function altrows(classname,firstcolor,secondcolor)
{
   var tableElements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname) ;
   for(var j= 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
   {
      var table = tableElements[j] ;

      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
      {
        rows[i].bgColor = (i%2==0) ? firstcolor : secondcolor ;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: In that case you could probably get away with looping over every row, but replacing `(i%2==0)` with `(i%3==0)`(so it only shows the first colour (red) for the first of every three rows)

Answer (score 5):

`rows[i]` will always exists, but `rows[i + 1]` might not exists. Then `rows[i+1].bgColor = secondcolor ;` causes some kind of fatal error that breaks whole script.

1. Consider using CSS:

   ```
   table tr:nth-child(even) {
       background-color: red;
   }

   table tr:nth-child(odd) {
       background-color: blue;
   }
   ```
2. Or use fixed JS:

   function altrows(classname,firstcolor,secondcolor)
   {
       var tableElements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname) ;

   ```
   for(var j = 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
   {
       var table = tableElements[j] ;

       var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
       for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
       {
           rows[i].bgColor = i % 2 == 0 ? firstcolor : secondcolor ;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: +1 for CSS solution. Sadly, IE8 doesn't support `nth-child`, and others have difficulties when nodes are dynamically inserted/removed (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t39).

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: @Anonymous You could use `tr:nth-child(3n){background: red;} tr:nth-child(3n+1){background: blue;} tr:nth-child(3n+2){background: blue;}`

Comment: Thanks. An how would that look in a for loop? I'm looking for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: I know I need to change this i % 2 == 0, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Zebra striping is easy with jQuery. [Check it](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy). Worth using and understanding and you can implement the same.

[Sitepoint](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/background-colors-javascript) has a good tutorial doing it using just javascript. no jquery.

Comment: @Gregoire, I never said jquery is the solution, I gave both the solutions jQuery and the regular one, I pointed to the right resource which has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function altrows(classname,firstcolor,secondcolor)
{
    var tableElements = document.getElementsByClassName(classname) ;
    for(var j = 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
    {
        var table = tableElements[j] ;

        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
        for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0){
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = firstcolor ;
            }
            else{
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = secondcolor ;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  Using this script the 1st table doesn't even alternate

Comment: @quoc: what happens if you put alert(tableElements.length);  before the first for?

Comment: putting alert(tableElements.length); before the 1st for I'm getting nothing different in FF 3.6 and IE 8

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is prob not the answer you looking for but here is a quick and easy way of alternating the row color with just 2 lines of jquery :)

$('tr:odd').css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");

$('tr:even').css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");